Using avatar fivem-server-api I get the error "require is not defined"
I want to communicate with fiveM API to get the server infos ect... so I use the avatar
fivem-server-api : text.
There is a lot of require like in line 1 where I get the error
const FiveM = require("../../node_modules/fivem-server-api");
but I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"
I've tried different thing I've seen on google but none work.
